# In functional programming, Is it 'bad' to access a partial function's parameter values?

Tags: functional-programming

I would like to create a function that converts one partial function into another. To do that, it must access the values of the partial function's parameters.

Is that considered anti-fp?

I'm thinking it is ok, as I'm not mutating anything, I'm only using data within the functions scope, and it returns a partial function with the same input type and output type.

I'm asking this generally, but can provide some code if needed. This is my first question here.

Comment: I guess it's difficult to know exactly what you mean by "accessing the values" of parameters. Some code would likely help us help you. If you're not doing mutation or reflection, it's probably fine. Partial functions aren't very functional to begin with, though. Depending on language, there are probably built-in ways to help you do the composition.

Comment: I was thinking of something like accessing 1 from the function increment in the following example: 

`add     :: Int -> Int -> Int  
x y = x + y  
increment = add 1`  

  
But I realise now I can just structure the data differently and avoid the need for this. I'd still be curious to know if it's possible in Haskell or other functional languages if you know?

Comment: It is still not totally clear what you intended to do. This reminds me that I have performed computations in "curried functions" before they were fully applied as an optimisation. The last argument was applied in a loop or in an animation frame. It is not very often that you can perform work without all the arguments and this could be a sign that your function is doing too many things and should instead accept the result of the computation as an argument, but it is not anti-fp: it's simply that your function is not a curried function, rather a more general higher order function.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the purpose of the example! Say I have 20 different increment functions in a list. Can I access the number they increment by?  Or is that 'property' of the partial function hidden from me?

Comment: It's hidden from you. You could simply pass around a `(function, value)` pair and apply the value later, or use the Reader monad.